# How to persist DuckDuckGo settings in Firefox without a permanent cookie?

Tags: firefox, duckduckgo, firefox-extensions

DuckDuckGo offers 4 methods of storing its settings:

1. Cookies. The most obvious choice, but not for this use case - the whole idea of switching to DuckDuckGo is to avoid being tracked.
2. URL with embedded setting codes. Works great when I open DDG start page with a bookmark. Sadly, there is no way to add setting codes to the URL when I select some text in a web page and rightclick it to search with DDG.
3. JSON. Useful only for their Answers API unless I'm missing something here.
4. Server-side storage with a passphrase. Inconvenient and readily identifiable.

So, any suggestions? I really do not understand why these settings are not in the add-on settings dialog, but it's of course a whole different story.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom search engine in most (all?) modern browsers. Simply take the URL with embedded setting codes and append `&q=%s` to the end of the URL, and use this as your default search engine in your browser. Alternatively, you can use the "Cloud Save Bookmarklet URL" to have these settings sync with your cloud save (and similarly append `&q=%s` when saving as a custom search engine).

Google Chrome - [Set your default search engine](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426)

Microsoft Edge - [Change your default search engine in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/change-your-default-search-engine-in-microsoft-edge-cccaf51c-a4df-a43e-8036-d4d2c527a791)

Mozilla Firefox - [Add or remove a search engine in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox)

Comment: This question is specific to DuckDuckGo in Firefox. Please clarify how this answers the question.